# Use Input value and send that with POST request to add to resource in React

Tags: reactjs

I am working in my React app. I have a button that adds an event. There is a drop down menu in there with 2 names. You can choose a name and when the other things are filled in, you can submit it and the information gets added to the server --> http://localhost:3000/events. I can also see the event is added in the browser. The problem is that when I look at the added event, the place where the name should be shown, says unknown. It is like the name that I chose when I made the event, doesn't get posted and I don't know what I am doing wrong (probably) in my code.

```
//This is my form component:

export const loader = async ({ params }) => {
  const categories = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/categories")
  const users = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/users")
  const event = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/events")

  return {
    event: await event.json(),
    categories: await categories.json(),
    users: await users.json()
  }
}

export const FormPage = () => {
  const [selectedCategories, setSelectedCategories] = useState([])
  const [selectedUser, setSelectedUser] = useState("") //state of user choice
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("")
  const [description, setDescription] = useState("")
  const [startTime, setStartTime] = useState(0)
  const [endTime, setEndTime] = useState(0)
  const [image, setImage] = useState("")
  //const [location, setLocation] = useState("")
  const [isPending, setIsPending] = useState(false)

  const navigate = useNavigate()
  const toast = useToast()

  const { categories, event, users } = useLoaderData()

  const showToast = () => {
    toast({
      title: "Submit",
      description: "new event succesfully added",
      duration: 3000,
      isClosable: true,
      status: "success",
      position: "top"
    })
  }

  const handleChange = e => {
    setSelectedUser(e.target.value)
  }

  const handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const addEvent = {
      title: title,
      createdBy: selectedUser,   //id and value from the selection in the jsx
      description: description,
      startTime: startTime,
      endTime: endTime,
      image: image,
      categoryIds: []
    }

    addEvent.categoryIds = selectedCategories

    setIsPending(true)

    try {
      fetch("http://localhost:3000/events", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify(addEvent)
      })


      setIsPending(false)
      showToast()
      navigate("/")

      if (response.ok) {
        alert("Resource updated successfully")
        navigate("/")
      } else {
        alert("Failed to update resource")
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error:", error)
    }
  }

  return (
    <Box>
      <AbsoluteCenter>
        <Card>
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <CardBody>
              <div className="container-body">
                <p style={{ marginTop: "40px", marginLeft: "5px" }}>Titel:</p>
                <input type="text" name="title" onChange={e => setTitle(e.target.value)} className="input-form" />
                <p style={{ marginLeft: "5px" }}>Description:</p>
                <textarea name="description" onChange={e => setDescription(e.target.value)} className="textarea-form"></textarea>
                <FilterBar activeCategories={selectedCategories} setActiveCategories={setSelectedCategories} categories={categories} />
                <input type="file" name="image" id="fileInput" accept="image/*" onChange={handleFileChange} />

**This is the drop-down I'm talking about**
                <div>
                  <select onChange={handleChange} id="createdBy" value={selectedUser} required className="dropdown">
                    {users.map(user => (
                      <option key={user.id} value={user.id}>
                        {user.name}
                      </option>
                    ))}
                  </select>
                </div>


                <div className="container-date">
                  <div className="date-start">
                    <span>Start time:</span>
                    <input className="input-date" type="datetime-local" onChange={e => setStartTime(e.target.value)} /> <br></br>
                  </div>

                  <div>
                    <span>End time:</span>
                    <input className="input-date" type="datetime-local" onChange={e => setEndTime(e.target.value)} />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </CardBody>
            <Divider />
            <CardFooter className="footer-form">
              {!isPending && <CButton type="submit">Submit</CButton>}
              {isPending && <CButton>adding event...</CButton>}
            </CardFooter>
          </form>
        </Card>
      </AbsoluteCenter>
    </Box>
  )
}
```

```
This is my eventPage component:

export const eventDetailsLoader = async ({ params }) => {
  const event = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/events/${params.eventId}`)
  const categories = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/categories")
  const users = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/users")

  return {
    event: await event.json(),
    categories: await categories.json(),
    users: await users.json()
  }
}

export const EventPage = () => {
  const { event, categories, users } = useLoaderData()

  const categoryIds = Array.isArray(event.categoryIds) ? event.categoryIds : []
  const categoryNames = categoryIds.map(id => categories.find(category => category.id === id)?.name || "Unknown")

  const reverseString = date => {
    const splitDate = date.split("-")
    const reverseArray = splitDate.reverse()
    const joinArray = reverseArray.join("-")
    return joinArray
  }

  const user = users.find(user => user.id === event.createdBy) || {}
  const finalEvent = {
    ...event,
    date: reverseString((event.startTime || "").slice(0, 10).toString() || ""),
    startTime: event.startTime ? event.startTime.split("T")[1]?.slice(0, 5).toString() : "",
    endTime: event.endTime ? event.endTime.split("T")[1]?.slice(0, 5).toString() : "",
    categoryNames: categoryNames,
    userName: user.name || "Unknown",
    userImage: user.image || "DefaultImageURL"
  }

  const text = (label, content) => (
    <Flex>
      <Text fontStyle="italic" fontWeight="bold">
        {label}
        {":"}
      </Text>

      <Text style={{ marginLeft: "30px" }}>{content}</Text>
    </Flex>
  )

  const listItems = items => (
    <List>
      {items.map((item, index) => (
        <ListItem key={index}>{item}</ListItem>
      ))}
    </List>
  )

  return (
    <Center display="flex" flexDir="column">
      <Card minW={450} h="full" mt={300}>
        <CardHeader fontWeight="bold">
          <h1>{finalEvent.title}</h1>
          <CardHeader m={0} p={0}>
            <Flex flexDir="column" color="white">
              <Image src={finalEvent.image} w="75%" h="30em" />
            </Flex>
          </CardHeader>
        </CardHeader>

        <CardBody align="center">
          {text("Activity", finalEvent.description)}
          {text("Date", finalEvent.date)}

          {text("Time", `${finalEvent.startTime} - ${finalEvent.endTime}h`)}
          {text("Location", finalEvent.location)}
        </CardBody>
        <hr />

        <CardFooter pl={-5} pr={0}>
          <Flex w="100%">
            <Box w="50%">
              <Tag size="lg" borderRadius="full" bgColor="white">
                <Avatar src={finalEvent.userImage} size="md" name={finalEvent.userName} ml={3} mr={3} />
                <TagLabel font={9}> {finalEvent.userName}</TagLabel>
              </Tag>
            </Box>
            <Spacer />

            <Box w="16.5%"></Box>
            <Spacer />

            <Spacer />
            <Box w="16.5%">
              <Link to={"/"}>
                <Button colorScheme="purple" size="l" padding={4}>
                  back
                </Button>
              </Link>
            </Box>
          </Flex>
        </CardFooter>
      </Card>
    </Center>
  )
}
```

Comment: Data is ok, so it is a rendering problem. Right after submitting data, `useLoaderData()` retrieves the latest data? You can check it using `console.log(user)` just before `return (<Box>,,,,,`

Comment: Thank you for your message @i2i3. I logged it and opened up the dev tools. It then shows the properties of both users (id, name and image). I also logged the state "selectedUser" and when I change names in the dropdown list, the console also shows the id numbers changing so state also seems te work.. useLoaderData() indeed retrieves the latest data.

Comment: Thanks @ECode, it seems to be ok. Btw, I noticed that you don't put `await` before `fetch("http://localhost:3000/events",,,` in handleSubmit, which may affect. Or to be honest, if you control select options with `useState`, everything is gonna be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have emulated as simplifying your project. For me, nextjs and typescript are at handy.

It works successfully. So I think your program has only rendering timing problem.

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import database from './database';

// Sample is made by nextjs
// pages/index.tsx
export default function FormPage() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');
  const [selectedUser, setSelectedUser] = useState('');

  // For triggering render purpose
  const [isModified, setIsModified] = useState(false);

  // Datastore substituting for api calls
  const users = database.read();

  const handleChange = (e: any) => {
    setSelectedUser(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      // Substituting for post fetch
      database.add({ id: `${value}:1`, name: value });

      // Triggering render for Select options updating
      setIsModified(!isModified);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input value={value} onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)} />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      {/* **This is the drop-down I'm talking about** */}
      <div>
        <select onChange={handleChange} id="createdBy" value={selectedUser} required>
          {users.map((user) => (
            <option key={user.id} value={user.id}>
              {user.name}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}
```

database

```
class Database {
  dataList: { id: string; name: string }[] = [{ id: '1', name: 'Initial value' }];

  add(data: { id: string; name: string }) {
    this.dataList.push(data);
  }

  read() {
    return this.dataList;
  }
}

const database = new Database();
export default database;
```